# Why isn't z-index working here

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make images overlap , I should see all of 'Adobe' of the first image ,  but e was blocked by the second one , so does the third.

[image]

I use diferent z-index to make the left-most image shows at top of stack , but it doesn't work here. Is it wrong to use margin-left with negative value ?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <style>
            li {
                float: left;
                display: inline;
                margin-left: -20px;
            }
            .A {
                z-index: 10;
            }
            .B {
                z-index: 9;
                margin-top: 3px;
            }
            .C {
                margin-top: 6px;
                z-index: 8;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><img class="A" src='adobe.gif' /></li>
            <li><img class="B" src='adobe.gif' /></li>
            <li><img class="C" src='adobe.gif' /></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `>` in your example... I doubt that's it, but it'll throw off a lot of answerers (such as myself)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add this rule:

```
li img {
    position: relative;
}
```

Or another value of `position`, as the definition of `z-index` says it only works on positioned elements.

Comment: That is, `position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

**JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/itepeg**

Tweak your code like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.A
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:-1;
}
.B
{
position:absolute;
left:40px;
top:10px;
z-index:-1;
}
  .C
{
position:absolute;
left:80px;
top:20px;
z-index:-1;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

  
  <ul>
            <li><img class="A" src='http://l.yimg.com/cv/ip/ap/default/111202/vs_fc.jpg'></li>
            <li><img class="B" src='http://l.yimg.com/cv/ip/ap/default/111202/vs_fc.jpg'></li>
            <li><img class="C" src='http://l.yimg.com/cv/ip/ap/default/111202/vs_fc.jpg'></li>
        </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

**JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/itepeg**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear the combination of tags is your problem here - gradually margin-left'ing while attempting to enforce a z-index isn't ideal.  Do you want them to overlap or to appear one on top of the other?

If one on top of the other, then I'd be tempted to suggest your UL/LI combo isn't necessary and just having a:

```
<div class="image_container">
  <img class="A">
  <img class="B">
  <img class="C">
</div>
```

and having CSS thus:

```
.image_container {
    position: relative;
    width: <widest image width>;
    height: <highest image height>;
}

.image_container img {
    position: absolute;
}

.image_container img.A {
   z-index: 10;
}
.image_container img.B {
   z-index: 9;
}

etc.
```

I'm not 100% sure on what you mean by overlap though - it may be you want to achieve roughly what you have just not with the overlap?
.

Comment: Just overlap like poker cards , partially

Comment: ahh, then @AlphaMale's extension to your task should do what you want - it's far easier to work with relatively absolute positioning than it is to work with floats (not that floats are wrong, just most people 'get' relatively absolute far more readily than they get floating in the way you have used it.   In this situation it feels like the best answer.