# Clip-path not working with z-index

Tags: css, z-index, clip-path

I am having trouble placing a container on top of another container that uses a clipped-path. I have tried using z-index on either of the containers but it doesn't seem to help.

If I remove the clipped-path class from the container then the block slides happily over the container. I have included [a fiddle of my problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/6jn6px4k/28/)

Here is my code:

```js
window.onscroll = function(){
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var para = Math.round(scrollTop / 1.2);
  document.querySelector('#block').style.transform = "translate3d(0px," + para + "px,0px)";
}
```

```css
body {margin: 5px;}

#main {height:100vh;}
#below-main {height:100vh;}
#row1 {height:100vh;}


/* Paralellogram to slide underneath block
--------------------------------------------- */
#bluestripe {  
  height: 60vh;
  width:60vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {width: 100%;}

.clip-polygon {clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 40%, 0 100%, 0 60%);}


/* Block to sit above parallelogram
--------------------------------------------- */
#block {
  height: 50px;
  width:100px;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="block">This needs to slide on top</div>
      <div id="bluestripe">
        <img id="sea" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/6644/sea-water-ocean-waves.jpg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="" class="clip-polygon">
      </div>
    <div id="row1"></div>   
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477859/why-isnt-z-index-working-here

Answer (score 4):

To affect an element's `z-index`, it must have `position` set to something other than `static` (the default).

In the case of your `#block`, it has no `position` set, so it is using the layer implied by the element's order in the source: it appears in your source before your clipped element, and naturally settles below it.

To position it on a higher `z-index` in the stack, give it a `position` and a `z-index`:

```
#block {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    transform: translate3d(0px,95px,0px);
    background-color: #999;
    position: relative; /* Allows z-index to take affect */
    z-index: 2; /* Stacks it above the clipped layer, which has no position nor z-index and is at z-index 1 */
}
```

Comment: This may be the correct answer, but I'm not sure if it completely explains the question. Why does a clip path effect the original post the way it does? How does it change or interact with z-index?

Comment: IIRC, it wasn't an issue with `clip-path`. The actual issue was that OP wanted one element to stack on top of another and wasn't using `z-index` to do so.

Comment: It was an issue with `clip-path`. Even with positioned elements, the `z-index` doesn't work anymore when they're clipped. See e.g. https://codepen.io/IcarusFW/pen/RaROeq?editors=0100. @DavidA.French